# live server page loads infinitely

Tags: javascript, html, liveserver

I'm a beginner to coding and more specifically JavaScript and html stuff, and right now I'm just trying to draw a square and make it move to the right. However, when I try to create my server then it just loads the page forever, making it so that I am unable to test my code. Is there any way that I can make it so that my page will actually load? here is my code so far:

html:

```
<html>
    <canvas id = 'canvas' height = '500' width = '500'></canvas>
    <script src = 'sus.js'></script>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

ctx.beginPath()
ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, 500, 500)

let x = 50
while(true){
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.fillRect(x, 50, 50, 50)
    x++
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in your loop?

Comment: When will the while(true) becomes false ? Right now I don't see why wouldn't the browser overflows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented and I will answer as well.

`while(true)` means - run infinitely, because there is no stopping point for the loop.

Try to set the while loop to run until x will be bigger to 200.

```
while(x <= 200){
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.fillRect(x, 50, 50, 50)
    x++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had an infinite loop running in my JS file, so my html file would simply sit for eternity waiting for my JS file to return something. Therefore, loading infinitely.